# What does PHP keyword 'var' do?

Tags: php, keyword

This is probably a very trivial question, but I haven't been able to find the answer neither through web search engines, nor on php.net. Please just direct me to where I can read about this, if you haven't got time to explain.

1. What does the 'var' keyword mean in PHP?
2. Are there any differences between PHP4 and PHP5?

Comment: I guess when you asked this question on July 30th, 2009, this had not been published yet at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php?: "Note: The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an E_STRICT warning." Or maybe you had not found it. But the answer is clearly stated at php.net.

Comment: That's really amazing to see what journeys PHP has passed these years!

Answer (score 394, accepted):

It's for declaring class member variables in PHP4, and is no longer needed. It will work in PHP5, but will raise an `E_STRICT` warning in PHP from version 5.0.0 up to version 5.1.2, as of when it was deprecated. Since PHP 5.3, var has been un-deprecated and is a synonym for 'public'.

Example usage:

```
class foo {
    var $x = 'y'; // or you can use public like...
    public $x = 'y'; //this is also a class member variables.
    function bar() {
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Note: The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the `var` keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the `public` keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an `E_STRICT` warning."_ http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php EDIT: I just saw that is has already been quoted [in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3844703/517705). But you should edit yours accordingly.

Comment: This implies that it is *necessary* to use the `public` keyword with for a member variable. Is that true? Can't one simply put `$x;`?

Comment: so is it recommended to just stick with public/private and ignoring var entirely since we aren't worried about working with deprecated versions of PHP?

Comment: As of 2019: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#43-properties-and-constants states that `var` must not be used, and visibility must be declared on all properties.

Answer (score 79):

The `var` keyword is used to [declare variables in a class in PHP 4](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php):

```
class Foo {
    var $bar;
}
```

With PHP 5 [property and method visibility](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) (`public`, `protected` and `private`) was introduced and thus `var` is deprecated.

Comment: In PHP 5.3 `var` is de-deprecated :)

Comment: If it's de-deprecated, what's the best practice now in 5.3 - to use it or not to use it? Can you use it like `private var $foo = 'bar';`?

Comment: Anyone know why it was de-deprecated?

Comment: It was undeprecated [in 5.1.3](http://www.php.net/releases/5_1_3.php) - the only reasons given are ["for compatibility reasons"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).  I think best practice is to use it only if you need to be compatible with PHP 4.  Certainly don't do `private var` - that will break things real quick, as `var` is just a synonym for `public` in PHP 5.

Comment: `var` is not a true synonym for `public` as it cannot be used for declaring static members or constants.

Comment: @Colin O'Dell's comment is the best =)

Answer (score 27):

I quote from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

> Note:  The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an `E_STRICT` warning.

Comment: I did tests. No returned E_STRICT ! http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/84652903a92588c23085e688803abfaf0c26a822

Comment: @WallacedeSouza, that's because you have used PHP 7 in your example.     It was invalid only in versions 5.0 - 5.1.3

Answer (score 8):

**Answer:** From **php** 5.3 and `>`, the `var` keyword is equivalent to `public` when declaring variables inside a class.

```
class myClass {
  var $x;
}
```

is the same as (for **php** 5.3 and `>`):

```
class myClass {
  public $x;
}
```

**History:** It was previously the norm for declaring variables in classes, though later became depreciated, but later (PHP 5.3) it became un-depreciated.

Answer (score 7):

So basically it is an old style and do not use it for newer version of PHP. Better to use Public keyword instead;if you are not in love with var keyword. So instead of using

```
class Test {
    var $name;
}
```

Use

```
class Test {
   public $name;
}
```

Comment: why you say that?  is there news of `var` being deprecated that I havent heard?  the two should be synonymous

Comment: From the PHP manual: "The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword)." https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 2):

var is used like public .if a varable is declared like this in a class
      var $a;
if means its scope is public for the class.
  in simplea words var ~public

```
var $a;
public
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP7.3 still working...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

> If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.

Answer (score 1):

here and now in `2018` using `var` for variable declaration is synonymous with `public` as in

```
class Sample{
    var $usingVar;
    public $usingPublic;

    function .....

}
```