# Calling functions from within each other not working

Tags: php

here's the code!.Not working,Please help.

```
class user{
var idgen;

function uid(){
    //return uniqid (rand(), true);
    return "123";
    }

function gen() {
    $this->idgen=$this->uid();
            //$this->idgen=udi();//even this dint work
    }

function pint() {
    echo "The id is :".$this->idgen;
    }
}

$use= new user();
$use->gen();
$use->pint();
```

Comment: Please post the output of the program as well, or "no output" if it's not doing anything.

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: its a web page.I'm not able to c any output.The above code is within <?php ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second line of your code to

```
private $idgen;
```

and voila! :)

BTW it's worth setting error reporting on; it really helps debugging.

You can do it by editing the `php.ini` file or adding this somewhere in your project:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); // <-- change this to off when live.
```

Put this in a file with other settings and include it in every page.

Comment: Thanks a ton.was trying to get firephp to work with firephp.Never got it working though.This'll cut short my debugging time 4 sure.Thanks a ton!!..

Answer (score 3):

`public $idgen;` instead of `var idgen;`

Comment: i want the $idgen to be a private member!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var idgen;
```

With:

```
public $idgen = '';
```

Comment: i want the $idgen to be a private member!

Comment: @Php: no prob. Just use `private $idgen;`. And make sure you include that *little issue* in your question to get proper help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[`var` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do), and you forgot the `$` in `$idgen`:

```
class user {
   private $idgen;

   // ... functions
}
```

You should activate **error reporting** on your webserver. Your original code will have generated an error; you just couldn't see it.

Comment: @Php: Did you understand the reasons for your original code being broken?

Comment: Yeah.M guessing the Missing $ resulted in ERROR :(

Comment: @Php: That's right. The member variable is still called `$idgen`, even though you don't write `$this->$idgen` but `$this->idgen`.

Comment: Yup.Dealt wit the same issue b4.Repeated the same mistake again.Hoping with the error reporting turned on, all my silly mistakes should be solved in the furture.

Answer (score 0):

First make a __constructor function, and add a "$" to the var definition.

```
class user{

public $idgen;

function __constructor(){
    $this->gen();
}

function uid(){
    //return uniqid (rand(), true);
    return "123";
}

function gen() {
    $this->idgen=$this->uid();
    //$this->idgen=udi();//even this dint work
}

function pint() {
    echo "The id is :".$this->idgen;
}
}

$use= new user();
$use->pint();
```

Give your defined variables a default value... never assume that they will be given a value through the processing of class.

Comment: Why did you change `gen()` to be run through a constructor? It makes sense but it's completely orthogonal to the question.

Comment: To give $idgen a predefined value.

Comment: And what does that have to do with the question?