# Php: simple code validation failure

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently working on a simple php function for an entity in the framework Symfony2. That function keeps generating errors, although I cannot see what is wrong. Here's the code :

```
public function getForm(array $reqFields){
    var $formHelper = new FormHelper;
    var $fields = new array;

    if($reqFields == null){
        foreach ($this->getArray() as $k => $v) {
            array_push($fields, $formHelper->getTextField($v, $k));
        }
    }

    return $formHelper->getForm($fields);
}
```

I've imported FormHelper, and the functions in it exist, for that matter. When I execute it, I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR
```

What's the problem?

Edit: Netbeans tells me that $reqFields should be initialized (but it's an argument :/), and that an identifier is expected on the return line.

Comment: On what line do you have this error?

Comment: `var` are only used in `class`

Comment: I believe it was on the third one. But the problem is resolved now, thanks to Aron's answer

Comment: @islandmyth and on PHP4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I notice ***two things at least***:

- Arrays are not objects. You cannot create an array instance like you do with `new array`.
- The `var` keyword is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do) as of PHP 5.3. (And you are using it wrong)

So your code:

```
var $formHelper = new FormHelper;
var $fields = new array;
```

**Should become:**

```
$formHelper = new FormHelper;
$fields = array();
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays arent objects!
So it is:

```
var $fields = array();
```

And you have to define class variables in the class header not in the function. So you should erase `var` in front too.

Like this:

```
class Foo
{
   public $fields = array(); // var equals public (you should use public, because var is deprecated)

   public function bar()
   {
      print_r($this->fields); // => Array ( )
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info (at least I'll know for sure what to use now), however, I still have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getForm(array $reqFields){
```

in php you don't declare the parameters type so you should transform it in

```
public function getForm($reqFields){
```

or

```
public function getForm($reqFields = array()){
```

if yout want the parameter to be optional
also

```
$formHelper = new FormHelper();
```

also

```
$fields = array();
```

also

```
foreach ($this->getArray() as $k => $v) {
```

I assume that $this is the form...if not use `$formHelper->getData();`

Comment: Typehinting an array, callable or class name is possible in function definitions, see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).