# Accessing Local database variable from function in the same class

Tags: php, mysqli

if plan to create database class to use it in any php project , so i write the basic class with little code below , but when test it i got error message 
**Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, *null given* in C:\AppServ\www\cms\includes\cmsDatabase.php on line 38**
Although i create connection in class constructor assigned to the local var.

My Code :

```
<?php
class cmsDatabase {


//Database Info 
var $db_host = "localhost";
var $db_username = "root";
var $db_password="root";
var $db_database= "mydb";

//Database Parameters 
var $database_connection ;
var     $database_db ;
var   $error_Message ;   

public function __construct(){
    $database_connection = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_username,$this->db_password,$this->db_database) or die("can't connect to server") ;

}// end __construct  

public function __destruct(){
    mysqli_close($this->database_connection);
}// end __destruct   


function getLastError(){
    return $this->error_Message  ;
    }


//==================== DATABASE OPERATIONS ======================
function getConnection(){
        return $this->database_connection ;
}

function selectQuery ($sql){

    $result = mysqli_query($this->database_connection,$sql); //>> ERROR HERE
    return $result ;

}




}//Class 



?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: it's different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use:

`$this->database_connection` in your constructor, otherwise its just a local variable and out of scope for your query.

Update: Oh and don't use var, it's deprecated in PHP 5: [What does PHP keyword 'var' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do)