# Redirecting a page using a select list form

Tags: php, joomla

I have been trying for most of the afternoon to do what I thought was a simple task. I am trying to redirect to different Joomla pages using a select list form.

I have created a select table with the suffix values of each item being a url.

From there I am using the statement

```
<form action="redirect.php<?php echo $_GET['page_url']?>" method="get">
```

to create a link that looks like this:

```
http://www.onlinelotto365.com/tools/jump.php?page_url=el-gordo-spain-cold-numbers
```

My redirect.php file looks like this:

```
<?php 
$suffix = var($_GET['url_suffix']);
header('Location: http://www.onlinelotto365.com/' . $suffix); 
?>
```

All I want to happen is for the page "http://www.onlinelotto365.com/el-gordo-spain-cold-numbers" to appear on the screen. Why am I making this so difficult? Can somebody please help.

Comment: Try: var_dump( $_GET );die(); Maybe the data is being escaped or url encoded?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please show the FUll html form code.

Comment: This does not make sense. What works and what does not work yet? Note that `var` is not a function and `redirect.php<?php echo $_GET['page_url']` most likely leads to a 404 unless `$_GET['page_url']` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please start from deleting depreciated var which is not a function btw

try:

```
<?php 
$suffix = $_GET['page_url'];
header('Location: http://www.onlinelotto365.com/' . $suffix); 
?>
```

var was used in php4 read more here [What does PHP keyword 'var' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do)

remember to get the parameter you set in URL that is page_url not url_suffix

Comment: This is getting me the desired page but now I am having trouble with the target because it is an iframe within a Joomla page.

Comment: I added a target="_parent" to the form submit line and that fixed things. Thanks for your help.