# Can this PHP code structure be improved?

Tags: php

I have class that stores data about network packet:

```
var $from_ip;
    var $to_ip;
    var $from_port;
    var $to_port;
    var $tcp_length;
    var $tcp_stream_text;
    var $tcp_stream;
    var $tcp_sequence_dec;
```

And now, I am creating function to print it:

```
function Print_data()
{
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "From IP:";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->from_ip;
        echo "</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "To IP:";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->to_ip;
        echo "</td></tr>";


    echo "</table>";

}
```

Is there any way to omptimize it? As you may notice there will be a lot of same lines. (Exept, may be write a function to show it). But what about vars?

Comment: do you have to print only specific `variable`?

Comment: You could try using arrays instead for iteration purposes

Comment: It's poor form. Separate your code.

Comment: Put your variables in an array

Comment: I guess you are getting confused when you have to echo so many variables at the same time and make HTML out of it. Obviously this code is difficult to manage. You can consider using template engines like Smarty => http://www.smarty.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [What does PHP keyword 'var' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do) says, var is deprecated.

Here s the solution I propose,

```
<?php

class TCP {
    protected $from_ip;
    protected $to_ip;
    protected $from_port;
    protected $to_port;
    protected $tcp_length;
    protected $tcp_stream_text;
    protected $tcp_stream;
    protected $tcp_sequence_dec;

    private $template = "<table>
        <tr>
            <td>From IP:</td>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>To IP:</td>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
    </table>";

    static public function render_template() {
        return sprintf(self::$template, self::$from_ip, self::$to_ip);
    }
}

print TCP::render_template();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variables [don't need the `var` on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do), but if they're in a class, I recommend defining their access level (`private`, `public`, `protected`, etc):

```
private $from_ip;
private $to_ip;
private $from_port;
private $to_port;
private $tcp_length;
private $tcp_stream_text;
private $tcp_stream;
private $tcp_sequence_dec;
```

And this is how I would (personally) write the `Print_data()` function:

```
function Print_data() {
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>From IP:</td>
            <td><?php echo $this->from_ip ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>To IP:</td>
            <td><?php echo $this->to_ip ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: why do we write `var` by the way?

Comment: @Mohammad You don't.  [You don't write var.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an array! Use the associate array to set the keys to whatever you want, I just referenced the variable name. And the values are simply the ones you have now.

```
$data = array(
    "To IP" => $to_ip,
    "From IP" => $from_port,
    "To Port" => $to_port,
    "TCP Length" => $tcp_length,
    "TCP Stream Text" => $tcp_stream_text,
    "TCP Stream" => $tcp_stream,
    "TCP Sequence Dec" => $tcp_sequence_dec
);
```

And then iterate! Use a foreach loop to get the key and value, and boom. Much cleaner

```
function Print_data() {
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work for your class

```
var $from_ip, $to_ip, $from_port, $to_port, $tcp_length, $tcp_stream_text, $tcp_stream, $tcp_sequence_dec;



function Print_data()
{
    echo <<<EOF
        <table>
            <tr><td>
            From IP:
            </td><td>
            $this->from_ip
            </td></tr>

            <tr><td>
            To IP:
            </td><td>
            $this->to_ip
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    EOF;

}
```

Comment: [You don't need to use `var`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the fastest, but i use something kinda like this for converting objects to assoc. arrays:

```
public function printObject($object)
{
    $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(get_class($object));        
    foreach ($reflectionClass->getProperties() as $property)
    {
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        echo "Prop: {$property->getName()}, Value: {$property->getValue($object)} \n";            
        $property->setAccessible(false);
    }
}
```