# get values from txt file in php

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

i know this will be easy for you but not for me :)

i need to get the contents of txt file "file.txt"

file.txt contetnt is

`word1
word2
word3`

each in a new line or can be as `word1, word2, word3,` or `"word1", "word2", "word3",` whichever is easier to do.

i have `config.php` file which i need it to read all and every word in `file.txt` and process as `$value` to be then processed by `script.php` which process `$value` as a single word of all the words in `file.txt`

thanks

Comment: So what is not working for you? You got the code right there.

Comment: All you need is [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function. It will read all the contents of your file in one array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file.php is as

```
<?php
    $words = array("word1", "word2", "word3");
 ?>
```

In another php file , say read.php, you can access file.php as

```
<?php

include "file.php";
print_r($words);
foreach($words as $value){
    echo $value;
//do whatever you want to do with each word
}

?>
```

Comment: is there a way to get words from `file.php` which uses the following format `var word = ["word1", "word2",];` instead ?

Comment: you need to get all the words of the file.php in an array? right?

Comment: Using regexes like that?! This would have been my last solution.

Comment: Did you try my code?? I think it satisfies your need.

Comment: @BlankHead, i'm sure it works but since i already have a php file it would be much better to use than to create another txt file and use
sorry for the trouble

Comment: ok, i have a `file.php` which have the following contents `var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3",];` lets say infinite number of words, i need php to read each and every word from `var words =` and treat them as `$value`

Comment: @BlankHead, my php file is exactly as `var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3",];`

Comment: You can't store the value like that in a php file. Its wrong format.
In javascript file we use like this. (it won't support in php5 and above.)
ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do

Comment: yes it's working for me with javascript, i thought it's possible also in php :) if not then i will try your answer now, sorry again for the trouble

Comment: Its my pleasure. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: @BlankHead, it didnt work :(
can you help me with easier way ?!
i have `config.php` file which will include the code you posted and `config.php` is included in `script.php` i need the `file.php` or `file.txt` which i think will be easier to make and add each `word` in new line to be read by `config.php` as `$value` to be read and process then by `script.php` as `$value` .and i'm sorry that i couldn't explain it more clear

Comment: @Ayman You say above that your file is `var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3",];` that is **JS syntax**. If anything, that file should most likely read as `$words = array("word1", "word2", "word3",);`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Let me know if you require an explanation about the code

```
<?php
$file = "filename.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$value = "";
foreach (explode("\n", $content) as $line) {
    // line is "word1", "word2", "word3", etc.
    $value .= $line . " ";
}
$value = trim($value); // Remove trailing space
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($lines as $value)

 $words= explode("\t",$value);`
```

use explode inside for each