# OOPS with OOP, PHP database connection

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

Hey guys I am developing a database connection with OOP PHP and I am stuck on this error;

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\Users...\function.php on line 26.

I am new to OOP so any help greatly appreciated

```
<?php
    class MyClass{
        var $HOST = "localhost";
        var $USER = "user";
        var $PASS = "pass";
        var $DB = "image_blog";
        public $con;

        function _construct(){
            $this->host = $HOST;
            $this->user = $USER;
            $this->pass = $PASS;
            $this->db = $DB;

            $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        }

        public function query($sql)
        {
            $query = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
            return $query;
        }
   }

   $obj = new Myclass;
   echo $obj->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
```

Comment: To avoid problems like this in the future, check the status of your connection before trying to use it: `if ($mysqli->connect_error) { die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error); }
`

Comment: I think your connection failed. Are you sure you are using the good `$HOST`, `$USER`, `$PASS` and `$DB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your constructor function must be `__construct` with **two** underscores, not one.

You can debug this sort of problem yourself.  Working backwards from the error, you would first do a `var_dump()` on `$this->con` (the first parameter for `mysqli_query()`).  This would show you that `$this->con` is not defined.  Next, you would go back to where you define and add a `die()` statement or similar to see if that code is even running.  You will find that it isn't.

From there, you could try copying/pasting in a known working function from the PHP documentation and then you would find that the constructor function would work.  All you have to do then is compare your two constructor functions, and it is likely you would immediately spot your error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $HOST = "localhost";
var $USER = "user";
var $PASS = "pass";
var $DB = "image_blog";
```

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206120/697370), you are using an outdated syntax for declaring class properties here (they are not, in fact, variables in and of themselves).  In your constructor (which others are right, is missing the first underscore), you are simply referencing undefined  local variables, rather than the properties themselves.  The solution here is to:

1. Add a second underscore prior to the `_construct` method to make it `__construct`, and
2. Change your constructor in regards to these properties.

I would suggest passing variables in as parameters to the constructor and set them that way (so that you would do `new MyClass( $host, $user, $pass, $db)`).  I would also change, instead of using the `var` keyword, to declare these properties like this:

```
protected $host = 'host';
// etc.
```

Another option could be to define them as constants, since, as you are using them currently, they can never really change anyway:

```
const HOST = 'host';
```

And you can reference them later as:

```
self::HOST
```

Here's a relevant quote from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> In order to maintain backward compatibility with PHP 4, PHP 5 will
>   still accept the use of the keyword var in property declarations
>   instead of (or in addition to) public, protected, or private. However,
>   var is no longer required. In versions of PHP from 5.0 to 5.1.3, the
>   use of var was considered deprecated and would issue an E_STRICT
>   warning, but since PHP 5.1.3 it is no longer deprecated and does not
>   issue the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors start with 2 underscores `function __construct()`

Answer (score 0):

like others said, constructor start with 2 underscores, 
i am using following class and its work for me,

```
class maindb_con
{
    private $hostname;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    private $con;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->hostname = "**********";
        $this->username = "**********";
        $this->password = "**********";
        $this->dbname   = "**********";
        if(!mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password,$this->dbname))
        {
            echo'Error:: 1001 Couldnot connect to database. Please update hostname, username and password';
        }
        else
            $this->con=mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);

    }
    /*function maindb_con($hname, $uname, $pwd, $dbname)
    {
        $this->hostname = $hname;
        $this->username = $uname;
        $this->password = $pwd;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
    }*/
    function get_con()
    {
        mysql_select_db($this->dbname,$this->con);
        return $this->con;
    }
    function get_dbname()
    {
        return $this->dbname;
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        mysql_close($this->con);
    }
}
```

and you  can add following method to run query and get result or false if query couldnt run as you require

```
public function runQuery($query)
    {
        //echo "query on runQuery(): ".$query;
        if($result=mysql_query($query,$this->con)) //or die("couldnt run mysql_query on runQuery for ".$query)
            return $result;
        return false;
    }
```

or this class could be used in following way

```
$dbcon=new maindb_con();
        $con=$dbcon->get_con();
        //echo "query on runQuery(): ".$query;
        if($result=mysql_query($query,$con))
......
```

Please visit [here](https://github.com/narayangt/phpTable) which will give you advance oop programming in PHP and give feedback please ....

Answer (score 0):

security levels Changes 1

```
 define("DB_HOST", 'yourhostaname');  
    define("DB_USER", 'dbusername');  
    define("DB_PASSWORD", 'dbpassword');  
    define("DB_DATABSE", 'databasename');
```

security levels Changes 2

public to protected member variable.

1) your data base connection code is Procedural Style not for OOP

OOP Style : $this->con =new mysqli( $this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db)

2)  You should  change  construct function __construct()

3) Check condition if ($this->con->connect_error) die('Database error -> ' . $this->con->connect_error);

4)  Change echo $obj->query("SELECT * FROM posts"); to  print_r($obj->query("SELECT * FROM posts")); OR var_dumb
5)

```
public function query()
    {

        return $this->con;

    }
```

6) `obj->query("SELECT * FROM posts") or die(obj->error);`