# Expression is not allowed as field default value

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to make `$app` available for the whole class.

First, I get:

> "Expression is not allowed as field default value"

Second, on line 5, I get:

> Unidentified variable $app

How can I achieve my goal?

```
class UserController extends XController
{
    var $app = Yii::app();;
    public function init()
    {
        $test = $app;
```

Comment: Why 2 `semicolon ;` in this line `var $app = Yii::app();;` ??

Comment: use Yii; namespace for using app.

Comment: The default value for members must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call. 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can not call a method to set a default value for a variable in PHP, not even if it is a static method. Change it to be set in the constructor:

```
use Yii;

class UserController extends XController    
{
    var $app;

    function __construct() {
        $this->app = Yii::app();
    }

    public function init()    
    {
        $test = $this->app;
    } 
}
```

As a side note, you should not use the `var` keyword in PHP versions > 4, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do) for an explanation.