# Expression is not allowed as field default value (on oop)

Tags: php, oop

I have a connection.php class, which is just here for the connection string to my MySQL database using the PDO object.

Then, I call the connection.php class in a query.php page, but when I try to get the PDO object from connection.php, I get an error "Expression is not allowed as field default value". (btw, my IDE is phpstorm)

Here is connection.php

```
class connection
{
    private $host = "XXX";
    private $db = "XXX";
    private $login = "XXX";
    private $password = "XXX";

        public function conn()
        {
            try
            {
                $bddconn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->db, $this->login, $this->password);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo "Connection failed " . $e->getMessage();
            }
            return $bddconn;
        }
}
```

And here is query.php

```
class query extends connection
{
    public $bdd = parent::conn();

    public function checkUser($login, $password)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT login, password FROM user WHERE login = ? AND password = ?;';
        $req = $this->bdd->prepare($query);
        return $req->execute(array($login, $password));
    }
}
```

However, at this point the IDE displays the error "Expression is not allowed as field default value" on query.php line 2 (public $bdd = parent::conn();)

What is the problem on my code?

Comment: It's what it says, you can't have expressions (parent::conn() is an expression) as a default property value. Call it in `__construct` instead.

Comment: ....have you tried googling that error message? If any is given, link in your case, that is mostly helpful ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression is not allowed as field default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037368/expression-is-not-allowed-as-field-default-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public $bdd = parent::conn();
```

You can't set property value from a function in the property declaration

You must initialize property value in methods, for example in constructor

```
class query extends connection
{
    public $bdd;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->bdd = parent::conn();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the property is static?