# Expecting statement after if

Tags: php

It is my code:

```
<?php
   if (empty($_COOKIE["count"]) && empty($_COOKIE["date"])) {
      setcookie("count",1);
      setcookie("date",date("d.m.y H:i"));
   } else {
      var $c=$_COOKIE["count"];
   }
?>
```

And I get error: **expecting statement** before var $c. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do will help you

Answer (score 2):

The `var` keyword is deprecated and was for use in *classes*, which this code snippet is not.

> Note: The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an E_STRICT warning.

Just assign the variable normally:

```
$c = $_COOKIE['count'];
```

Otherwise, it is expecting to be inside of a class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable $c before the if statement.

```
   <?php
       $c = 0;
       if (empty($_COOKIE["count"]) && empty($_COOKIE["date"])) {
          setcookie("count",1);
          setcookie("date",date("d.m.y H:i"));
       } else {
          $c=$_COOKIE["count"];
       }
    ?>
```