# Accessing a local variable in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have this code:

```
class database{
    var $conn;
    function connect($server,$host_username,$host_password,$host_database){
        $server = 'localhost';
        $host_username = 'root';
        $host_password = '';
        $host_database = 'e-vent system db';

        $conn= new mysqli($server,$host_username,$host_password,$host_database);

        if ($conn->connect_error){
            die("db connection error:". $conn->connect_error);
        }
    }

    function read_db($table,$condition){
        $read="SELECT * FROM ".$table." ".$condition;
        $read_result=$conn->query($read);
        if(!$read_result){
            echo "select error:". mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\E-vent\database.php on line 19

How can I make the `$conn` variable visible to the `read_db` function?

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
if ($conn->connect_error){
```

to

```
if ($this->conn->connect_error){
```

means replace all:

```
$conn->query
```

to

```
$this->conn->query
```

**Explanation:** If you want to use a variable in the entire class scope then you have to use the class variable instead of local (function) scope variable. In this line:

```
$conn->connect_error
```

the `$conn` is a local variable whose scope is limited to the function only, but when you use `$this->conn`, it means you are referring to the class variable which is accessible in all the member functions of the class.

And put all the content of `connect` function in the class constructor so that this connection is initialized at the time of class initialization. (Thanks  @Magnus for pointing this)

Have a look on the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), it will help you to understand the concept.

Comment: I did that bu still throws the same error

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Also you are using v5.5+ you can use public, private, protected scopes to the variable `private $conn` which implies encapsulation

Comment: @Vic - An important note, you also need to _set_ that property: `$this->conn = new mysqli(...)` for it to exist in the other method.

Comment: @balakrishnan, yes that's why I have provide the variable scope help link

Answer (score 1):

You are using class variable into a function, it's basic rule of oops that to use class variable we must access it using object. so class variable can be used under same class using `$this`.

so your code must be:

```
$this->$conn->connect_error
```

Instead of

```
$conn->connect_error
```

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `$this->conn->connect_error`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the connection object a property of the class, using `$this` - specifically, `$this->conn`. Assign your connection-object to that property. You then need to reference `$this->conn` everywhere else within that class, instead of using `$conn`.

```
class database {
    public $conn;

    public function connect($server, $host_username, $host_password, $host_database)
    {
        $server = 'localhost';
        $host_username = 'root';
        $host_password = '';
        $host_database = 'e-vent system db';

        $this->conn = new mysqli($server, $host_username, $host_password, $host_database);

        if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
            die("db connection error:". $this->conn->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public function read_db($table, $condition)
    {
        $read = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." ".$condition;
        $read_result = $this->conn->query($read);
        if (!$read_result) {
            echo "select error:". mysqli_error($this->conn);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

That being said, a couple of things to note,

1. You are not using parameterized queries, and are injecting variables directly into the query -- **this is not secure**, and you should use a prepared statement with placeholders.
2. The `connect()` method takes in all the arguments, but you still overwrite them in the function. Alternatives are to remove the arguments, remove the hard-coded values, or use the hard-coded values if the argument is empty.
3. You should not return errors to the user while in production. During development, this is fine - but in production, hide them, log them and display something generic to the user instead (like a 500 page, or some other error page).
4. You should specify if your properties and methods are *public*, *protected*, *static*  or *private*.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use public access modifier without using var. [What does PHP keyword 'var' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do).

Class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.

And also The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an E_STRICT warning.

PHP variables - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Need to change as follows

```
class database{
    public $conn
```

And here

```
$this->conn= new mysqli($server,$host_username,$host_password,$host_database);
```

And here

```
if ($this->conn->connect_error){
    die("db connection error:". $this->conn->connect_error);
}
```

And here as well

```
$read_result=$this->conn->query($read);
```